# Burninate the [rtt] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [rtt](/questions/tagged/rtt) is only used for [a couple of questions (23)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rtt) but it is used as an abbreviation for a variety of different things like

- "render to texture"
- "re-transmit timeout"
- "real-time text"

but in most cases it is used for

- "round-trip time".

It seems like it should either be removed completely and all existing questions should be re-tagged

or

it should be given a tag description (which it is currently missing) that says that it's for "round-trip time" (since that is what it's *mostly* used for) and only questions with a different usage should be retagged.

What do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There already exits a tag for round-trip time questions: [roundtrip](/questions/tagged/roundtrip)

I have retagged all [rtt](/questions/tagged/rtt) questions:

- "render to texture" questions --> [render-to-texture](/questions/tagged/render-to-texture)
- "retransmit timeout" questions --> [retransmit-timeout](/questions/tagged/retransmit-timeout)
- "real-time text" questions --> [real-time-text](/questions/tagged/real-time-text)
- "round-trip time" questions --> [roundtrip](/questions/tagged/roundtrip)